# laravel 7 Validation unique multiple columns

Tags: laravel

how to viladate multiple columns

table name "exam_starts"

columns

```
id
exam_id 
exam_multi_id       
student_id  
exam_class_id   
exam_code_id    
Status

class Student extends Model
{
    //    exam
    public function exams(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Exam','exam_starts','student_id','exam_id')
            ->withPivot(['id','exam_multi_id','exam_class_id','exam_code_id','Attend','pass','Status'])- 
      >withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

how to unique columns student_id and exam_class_id  in table exam_starts ?

My Try in controller

```
class ExamClassController extends Controller
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'exam_class_id' => [
        'required',
        'integer',
         'unique:exam_startss,exam_class_id,'.$request->exam_class_id .',student_id' ,
    ],
    'student_id' => 'bail|required|integer',
    'exam_start_id' => 'bail|required|integer',
    'exam_id' => 'bail|required|integer',
    'exam_multi_id' => 'bail|required|integer',
    'code' => 'nullable|string',
    'student' => 'bail|required|string',
]);
 }
```

this mysql resulte

```
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `exam_starts` where `exam_class_id` = 1 and `student_id` <> 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Unique rule class and you can pass multiple wheres to it, to make an unique constraint that takes two columns.

```
(new Unique('exam_starts'))
    ->where('student_id ', $request->student_id)
    ->where('exam_class_id', $request->exam_class_id);
```

Set it into validation like so

```
'exam_class_id' => [
    'required',
    'integer',
    (new Unique('exam_starts'))
        ->where('student_id ', $request->student_id)
        ->where('exam_class_id', $request->exam_class_id),
],
```